# Prove all neighbourhoods are open in this topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set. We define the following topology on $X$:

$$\tau=\{S\subseteq X:X\setminus S\text{ is finite}\}$$

How do you prove all neighbourhoods are open in this topology.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\{S\subseteq X:X\setminus S\text{ is finite}\}\cup\{\varnothing\}$? And what is $k$?

Comment: its the c without the line underneath but apart from that yeah. i couldn't make it look right

Comment: sorry k is topology it's supposed to be tau but i don't know how to write things on here, what does it use?

Comment: It’s basically just $\LaTeX$; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get started.

Comment: is it in latex?

Comment: The displayed line that I wrote is, yes.

Comment: oh ok i can use latex fine, thanks

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\tau$ is the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $X$. Suppose that $x\in X$ and that $N$ is a nbhd of $x$. Then there is some $V\in\tau$ such that $x\in V\subseteq N$. Clearly $V\ne\varnothing$, so $X\setminus V$ is finite. What does that tell you about $X\setminus N$?

Comment: that it is finite?

Comment: Do i not use open balls? that seems to be the answer to everything?

Comment: @andwil: Yes: $X\setminus N$ must be finite, and therefore by definition $N\in\tau$, i.e., $N$ is open. You can’t use open balls unless you have a metric, and this is not a metric space.

Answer (score 1):

A neighbourhood $U$ of a point $x$ is any set that contains an open set $V$ containing $x$. So $U$ contains $V$, but $V$ is almost all of $X$. Then $U$ itself must contain all of $X$ minus a finite number of points and hence be open.